# angularjs two select with same model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am not sure if this is possible or not, i am having single data list (`ng-model`) which is getting passed to more then 4 select as below `HTML` code. When i select some option in one select box then all another selected value in all select box get un-selected, i guess because of same `ng-model` is used in more then 4 select box.

Controller :-

```
angular.module('App').controller('RoleDialogController',
    ['$scope','entity', 'RoleType',
        function($scope, entity,RoleType) {
        $scope.role = entity;
        $scope.roletypelist = RoleType.query();
});
```

HTML :-

```
<div class="form-group">
                        <label translate="App.role.role" for="field_regions">role</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="field_regions" multiple
                            name="roletype" ng-model="role.roletypelist"
                            ng-options="roletype as roletype.roleTypeName for roletype in froletypelist = (roletypelist | filter:search | rolelistfilter:120:130) track by roletype.id "></select>
                    </div>


<div class="form-group">
                        <label translate="App.role.products" for="field_regions">products</label>
                        <select class="form-control" id="field_regions" multiple
                            name="roletype" ng-model="role.roletypelist"
                            ng-options="roletype as roletype.roleTypeName for roletype in froletypelist = (roletypelist | filter:search | rolelistfilter:130:140) track by roletype.id "></select>
                    </div>
```

Comment: can't use the same alias for different filters that return different results. That alias is passed to the scope. Create demo that reproduces problem